# Possible reasons why a valid PHP class method would not work

Tags: php, class, methods

I have this perfectly valid and defined PHP class method that just refuses to work. I have this class:

```
class SessionHandler{
    public function startSession(){
        ....
        ....
    }

    public function endSession(){
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

So I instantiate object and call method:

```
$sessHandler=new SessionHandler();
$sessHandler->startSession();
```

It used to work, but somehow just stopped working, with this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SessionHandler::startSession() in C:\wamp\www\mywebapp\models\user.php on line 212
```

I have gone over the code and cannot find anything wrong. The class and method I called are very much valid and fully defined. So I'm just wondering if there's some kind of bug in `PHP` that causes this behaviour. I use `PHP version 5.4.16`

Comment: Are you sure `$sessHandler` is a valid `SessionHandler` object? Try `var_dump($sessHandler);` before running the member method to find that out

Comment: Perhaps you should post the actual code rather than the edited version of it. There's clearly something wrong, and you saying it's all OK isn't very convincing.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php

Comment: @kingkero If it wasn't, the error wouldn't have said that startSession() isn't on SessionHandler, but instead some other class, e.g.. `undefined method stdClass:: startSession()` or on no object at all, `Call to a member function startSession() on a non-object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP 5.4+ has it's own, built-in class named [`SessionHandler`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php). Since the class already exists, whatever autoloading strategy you're using is not loading your version of `SessionHandler`.

Comment: oh, my bad!! I didn't know that. I'd renamed my class and it's solved.

Comment: @okeyxyz: namespaces `:)`.